# How to leave a comment in npm page package?

Tags: javascript, npm

I want to ask about the properties of this package "https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-chartsjs-es6", 
I need to contact the collaborator.
Is that posible?

Comment: you can go to the [github](https://github.com/bitkill/vue-charts) for the package and make a pull request? I would say leave an issue but it appears they do not have those open

Comment: Alternatively, it would appear that package is actually forked from [this one](https://github.com/hchstera/vue-charts) which _does_ have issues open; if your question is about the core package and not the es6 port, the original creators might be able to help

Comment: This package has a [Github](https://github.com/bitkill/vue-charts) page. It is forked from [this](https://github.com/hchstera/vue-charts/issues) package, but I suggest you to make a pull request or create a new issue on the forked project.